# Filling causes tikz picture to jump in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, pdftex

I have an issue with a jumping tikz picture. The picture jumps when I add a filling, as you can see in the example below. Interestingly, this is an issue I am encoutering on my Mac, but not on my Ubuntu computer.

```
\documentclass[10pt, aspectratio=169]{beamer}


%%Theme stuffx
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{AAA}

  \def \myscale {0.9}

 \centering
  \pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
  axis line style={->}, % arrows on the axis
  xlabel={},          % default put x on x-axis
  ylabel={},          % default put y on y-axis
  ticks=none,
  grid=none,
  }}

    \centering
    \tikzset{>=stealth}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\myscale] %%def \myscale
    \begin{axis}[
    axis equal,
    axis x line* = center,
    axis y line* = center,
    xmin=-0.05,xmax=1.05,
    ymin=-0.05 ,ymax=1.05,
    scale=1.5,
    transform shape
    ]

  %% parameters
  \def \wtilde {0.25} %% phi(wtilde)=0
  \def \concav {2} %% phi has a power 1/concav
  \def \phimax {0.63} %% phi(1)=phimax

  \plot[name path=f1,thick, color = black, dotted, samples=100, domain=\wtilde:1] {\phimax * ( (x-\wtilde)/(1-    \wtilde) )^(1/\concav)};
  \plot[name path=X1,thick,opacity=0,samples=2,domain=\wtilde:1] {0};
  \plot[name path=X2,thick,opacity=0,samples=2,domain=0:\phimax] {1};

  \end{axis}

  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{AAA}

  \def \myscale {0.9}

 \centering
  \pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
  axis line style={->}, % arrows on the axis
  xlabel={},          % default put x on x-axis
  ylabel={},          % default put y on y-axis
  ticks=none,
  grid=none,
  }}

    \centering
    \tikzset{>=stealth}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\myscale] %%def \myscale
    \begin{axis}[
    axis equal,
    axis x line* = center,
    axis y line* = center,
    xmin=-0.05,xmax=1.05,
    ymin=-0.05 ,ymax=1.05,
    scale=1.5,
    transform shape
    ]

  %% parameters
  \def \wtilde {0.25} %% phi(wtilde)=0
  \def \concav {2} %% phi has a power 1/concav
  \def \phimax {0.63} %% phi(1)=phimax

  \plot[name path=f1,thick, color = black, dotted, samples=100, domain=\wtilde:1] {\phimax * ( (x-\wtilde)/(1-    \wtilde) )^(1/\concav)};
  \plot[name path=X1,thick,opacity=0,samples=2,domain=\wtilde:1] {0};
  \plot[name path=X2,thick,opacity=0,samples=2,domain=0:\phimax] {1};

  % %
  \addplot fill between[
  of = f1 and X1,
  soft clip={domain=0:1},
  every even segment/.style  = {black,opacity=1}
  ];

  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I can not reproduce the error. Is your LaTeX installation fully updated? You should always set `compat` level when using PGFPlots. `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}`

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your problem. In your document you may not have equal settings in both frames. To avoid possible discrepancies, I suggest to define common axis options for both images:

```
\documentclass[10pt, aspectratio=169]{beamer}

% Theme stuff 
\usetheme{Warsaw}
% general packages
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{mathtools}
% for drawing diagrams
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18,
PLOT/.style={   % common definition of diaghram styles
    height=\textheight,
    axis lines = center,
    axis line style={-Stealth}, % arrows on the axis
    grid=none,
    ticks=none,
    axis equal,
    xmin=-0.05,xmax=1.05,
    ymin=-0.05 ,ymax=1.05,
    xlabel={},          % default put x on x-axis
    ylabel={},          % default put y on y-axis
    every axis plot post/.append style={thick}
            }}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{AAA}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[PLOT]
%% parameters
\def \wtilde {0.25} % phi(wtilde)=0
\def \concav {2}    % phi has a power 1/concav
\def \phimax {0.63} % phi(1)=phimax
% diagram
  \plot[thick, dotted, samples=100, domain=\wtilde:1]
    {\phimax*((x-\wtilde)/(1-\wtilde))^(1/\concav)};
\end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{BBB}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[PLOT]
%% parameters
\def \wtilde {0.25} % phi(wtilde)=0
\def \concav {2}    % phi has a power 1/concav
\def \phimax {0.63} % phi(1)=phimax

\plot[name path=f1,dotted, samples=100, domain=\wtilde:1] {\phimax*((x-\wtilde)/(1-    \wtilde))^(1/\concav)};
\plot[name path=X1, opacity=0,samples=2,domain=\wtilde:1] {0};
% fill
  \addplot fill between[of=f1 and X1,
                        soft clip={domain=0:1},
                        every even segment/.style  = {black,opacity=1}
                        ];
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]